# Sublime Text 2 - missing tabs of currently opened

Tags: tabs, editor, sublimetext2

I started to play with Sublime Text 2 editor and it seems to be pretty cool, but there is one thing that makes me a little bit confused.

When I open a project and then I will open the files which I need to update, these files are not displayed in tabs in the top bar, as is shown in the screenshot?

How could I display them?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you actually opened the file (i.e. double clicked it from the sidebar) or are you just viewing the file preview, which by design, doesn't appear as a tab in the main window.

Comment: Oh, you were right. I just noticed that ST2 has 2 levels of opening - preview (1-click) and edit (2-click).

Comment: There wouldn't happen to be a way to configure this so a single click opens the file for editing (i.e., shows the tab)?

Comment: @EnisAfgan Just change something in the file and it opens a tab.

Comment: You can also set "preview_on_click": false in your settings to turn off the one-click preview. I haven't discovered how to enable one-click editing. Even with this setting, you still have to double-click a file. I'm uncertain which mode I prefer.

Comment: Just another example of a counter-intuitive default UX 'design' that developers seem to dream up from time-to-time...  at least it can be configured to go away.

Answer (score 5):

You can view the tabs by opening the command pallet by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (Mac) and typing  "View: Toggle Tabs" 
This toggles the file tabs.

Comment: @Thomas just checked your pending edit: both the hotkey and search string are correct in your edit. If it gets rejected, please contact me. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8880130

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue , I tried every thing but the open files are not showing

on the top of SUBLINE EDITOR , I double click each file but just show

on left side base not on top of SUBLINE as tab.

[image]