# NoClassDefFoundError for a class in the same package as another class that runs fine

Tags: java, maven, aem, osgi-bundle

I'm developing for AEM 6 and I am seeing a NoClassDefFoundError for one of my classes. Here is the setup of my maven project:

```
+- pom.xml
|
+- parent
|    |
|    '- pom.xml
|
+- content
|    |
|    '- pom.xml
|
'- bundles
     |
     +- pom.xml
     |
     +- taglib
     |    |
     |    '- pom.xml
     | 
     '- components
          |
          '- pom.xml
```

Here's a few more details on what is happening:

- The bundles pom specifies all child bundles as modules
- The content pom

  - specifies the packaging as content-package and contains the jcr_root
  - specifies both the taglib bundle and the components bundle as dependencies and embeddeds
- The taglib pom.xml has specified the components bundle as a dependency
- The components bundle has two classes generated: Component.class and ComponentFactory.class
- All of my installed **bundles are active** in `/system/console/bundles`
- The taglib bundle lists that it imports the package containing the classes
- The components bundle lists that it exports the package containing the classes

If I put add the line `Component component = new Component()` to the tag that I'm using in my jsp, the code runs fine. Loading with my page with the tag containing the code loads fine.

However, if I try to instantiate a ComponentFactory like `ComponentFactory factory = new ComponentFactory()`, the code will build completely fine and then fail at runtime. Loading my page with the tag results in a white page and the error logs have a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I looked into the error and it seems to be an issue of a class being available at compile time but not in the classpath at runtime which makes sense. My confusion is that both classes are in target/classes and the .classpath file doesn't seem to indicate why one would be excluded.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are about 20 different reasons for NoClassDefFoundError.  Eg, misspelling your class name in the .java file can do it.

Comment: Or putting the file in the wrong directory given the package declaration, or vice versa. Basically it means that the class found in the .class file wasn't the one indicated by the name & path of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I've verified that the paths are correct both under src as well as target. I have noticed that now there are other exceptions complaining about old pieces of code so there may be some issue with the updating of the bundles.

Comment: The issue was fixed after restarting my server. I will post an answer if I can figure out what was happening from the logs.

Comment: The further implication of my comment is that the .class file was being looked at in the expectation of it containing the class indicated by its name and path, and it wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks EJP. It must have been some issue with osgi being in a bad state and not managing the bundles correctly.

Comment: @Thomas commented on your last edit, please check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670946/sublime-text-2-missing-tabs-of-currently-opened/25307853#comment51058413_25307853